# Resize background color

Tags: windows, qt

I have a Windows app for which when the window is quickly made bigger pieces of "whitespace" are temporarily created.

Is there a way to make those pieces of whitespace *black*?

Comment: Dont think so, it depends on the speed of the App i guess. It can't be more than about a second right?

Comment: Rob: Yes, my app is not ultra fast. But it would look much less glitchy if the background was black. [Because I'm playing videos which have a black frame.]

Comment: Hmm ok, on what object you're setting the background-color? The form itself?

Comment: Well I'm not setting any "background color" at all. It seems that I would like to override a QT default or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [`autoFillBackground`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qwidget.html#autoFillBackground-prop) property of the window and have Qt paint the newly exposed background for you. There are some Windows specific attributes mentioned there, too. Mainly, `WA_NoSystemBackground` needs to be set to use a different background color.